# Can one java executable run more than one loop at the same time

Tags: java, eclipse, loops, concurrency, runtime

I use Eclipse KEPLER [I loved Eclipse JUNO version]
Warning: My English is not good at all, please correct me or notice me if senseless sentences found.

My problem is:
 I have a program which have a lot of loops inside of main loop and I noticed a critical failure, that will cause the whole program to get jammed for every 3 seconds and then it wake up again. [I would like to send the code, but it includes over 14 classes, so... perhaps I do not send it]

The problem is caused by loop(s), which take too long time to finish. If these "loops" are in "main loop" this "main loop" takes 3 seconds to start again [which is not acceptable]

Because mount of code, I wrote an example of my problem and it perhaps include possible solution, but I don't know how to do it:

```
    public class EX1 {
    static public String w="";      // something where program can storage stuff
    static public String alp="AaÁáÂâÄäÃãÅåÀàBbCcDdEeÉéÊêËëÈèFfGgHhIiÍíÎîÏïÌìJjKkLlMmNnÑñOoÓóÔôÖöÕõÒòPpQqRrSsTtUuÚúÛûÜüÙùVvWwXxYyÝýÿZz1234567890 ";

    public static void StuffThatSupposeToBeAlwaysOn(){      // As I told here is loop that suppose to be running all time
        int rand=0;                             // in this example, this loop works as random text generator
        for(int a=0;a<100;a++){
            rand=(int)(Math.random()*alp.length()-1);
            w=w+(alp.substring(rand,rand+1));
        }
    }
    public static void StuffThatSupposeToBeAlwaysOn2(){ //this suppose to be another same time running loop
        /*
         * printed String w should always be 16 letters long
         * but because program run both loops one by one, it simply can't print it right length (16)
         * so it print it as max length of loop (100)
         */
        for(int a=0;a<50;a++){
            if(w.length()>15){
                System.out.println("Randomly generated text: "+w+". length of text is: "+w.length());
                w="";
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {// main program

        long a=System.currentTimeMillis();
        while(a+2000>System.currentTimeMillis()){   //Main loop[automated kill after 2 seconds]

            StuffThatSupposeToBeAlwaysOn();         // so if I get both running at same time, problem is solved.
            StuffThatSupposeToBeAlwaysOn2();

        }System.exit(0);//program gets killed here
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, in case you multithread your application. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/

Comment: It looks like you have to learn how Runnable and Thread work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they're lagging your main loop, this is where multi-threading is of good use, that way each method can run on a separate thread and feedback to the main thread once complete, not slowing the things on the main thread.